# AWS Serverless Image Handler - Lambda Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-serverless

My Serverless image handler was working fine till now and  now i'm getting the following error.

start_thumbor error: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (nss)

This looks like a problem with the version of pycurl.

Please help me resolve it.

Tried changing the pythong version to 3.6 in ServerlessImageHandler lambda function configuration.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Something has changed on AWS lambda environment. I do not know yet how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a discussion about that issue on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=909444, which sent me to https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues/127#issuecomment-514757029.

Github user timkelty has the solution:

```
go to my CloudFormation Stack
click Update
"replace template"
paste in https://cf-templates-nestrom.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/serverless-image-handler/1.0/serverless-image-handler.template
so far has worked for me in us-east-1 and us-west-1
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS has released a new version of **Serverless Image Handler** this is why everybody suffers now because Thumbor functionalities fail in the new version.
In the new version, SharpJS is used instead of Thumbor API calls.

You can check the new version and download it from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/welcome.html).

Even though you are able to construct urls in old style, images in subfolders are not possible to access anymore without encoding the url.

Old way: 
    `abcdef.cloudfront.net/team/team1.png`

New way:
    `abcdef.cloudfront.net/{base64encodedPath}`

**Note 1:** If your images are in the root directory of the bucket, you are still able to access them old style like this:

```
abcdef.cloudfront.net/team1.png
```

**Note 2:** If you update your existing CloudFormation stack, you will have your old cloudfront domain (which is a good part).

You can also follow the current fixes from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues).

Comment: I tried encoding the file path but it's not working. The error says that ensure original image should be of a supported file type. The S3 filepath is `/student/images/std.jpg`. I gave the URL as `abcdef.cloudfront.net/fit-in/64x64/{base64encodedPath}`. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The above is no longer true. [They have fixed the issue with using "sub-folders" in S3 for Thumbor style URLs](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues/184#issuecomment-586003019).

They [also plan to support Thumbor style URLs for the foreseeable future](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues/184#issuecomment-586023450), or well, until the decide to just randomly change it.

The Thumbor implementation in version 4.2+ of the Serverless Image Handler is buggy because they rewrote it using NodeJS and using Sharp. So check out the other open issues.